# Scala js jQuery GET request result

Tags: ajax, scala, scala.js

I am completely new to JS, Ajax, etc and Scala JS. I have a small REST API, where i can send GET requests(e.g localhost:9000/stats?first=abc&second=cde&from=1482327698&to=1482327998)

How can i do it in Scala JS? I tried this:

```
  val successButton = Button(ButtonStyle.success)("Plot", onclick.:=(Bootstrap.jsClick(_ => {
  val subj1 = firstText.now
  val subj2 = secondText.now
  val now = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
  val from = now - 300

  val url = s"http://127.0.0.1:9000/stats?first=$subj1&second=$subj2&from=$from&to=$now"

  jQuery.get(url)
}))).render
```

But it gives me literally nothing. Thanks in advance

Comment: One comment first: since you're just starting out, you might want to switch to using the newer [jquery-facade](https://index.scala-lang.org/jducoeur/jquery-facade) instead of the older scala-js-jquery -- we're going to start deprecating the older version you're using here as soon as I can update the documentation.  The two have the same functionality, but the new one is a bit easier to use from Scala.

Comment: As to the specific question: have you checked whether the server is getting the request?  At first glance, I would expect this to send the request, but keep in mind that `jQuery.get` just returns a JQueryXHR structure -- it doesn't *do* anything browser-side unless you register a callback to execute when it's done.  Personally, I would put in some println's in both the server and here in the client, to make sure that everything is actually getting called...